# Difference between &rest parameter and list in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun highest (lat)
    (cond
        ((null lat) nil)
        ((null (cdr lat)) (car lat))
        (T (higher (car lat) (highest (cdr lat))))))

(defun higher (a1 a2)
    (cond
        ((> a1 a2) a1)
        (T a2)))
```

This function works as expected:

```
> (highest '(3 5 1 2 3))    
3. Trace: (HIGHEST '(3 5 1 2 3))
4. Trace: (HIGHEST '(5 1 2 3))
5. Trace: (HIGHEST '(1 2 3))
6. Trace: (HIGHEST '(2 3))
7. Trace: (HIGHEST '(3))
7. Trace: HIGHEST ==> 3    
6. Trace: HIGHEST ==> 3
5. Trace: HIGHEST ==> 3
4. Trace: HIGHEST ==> 5    
3. Trace: HIGHEST ==> 5
```

But if I change the parameter to `&rest`:

```
(defun highest (&rest args)
    (cond
        ((null args) nil)
        ((null (cdr args)) (car args))
        (T (higher (car args) (highest (cdr args))))))
```

It doesn't behave the same.

```
> (highest 3 5 1 2 3)
3. Trace: (HIGHEST '3 '5 '1 '2 '3)
4. Trace: (HIGHEST '(5 1 2 3))
4. Trace: HIGHEST ==> (5 1 2 3)
*** - >: (5 1 2 3) is not a real number
```

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I pass the arguments a atoms in the second case. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to evaluate (trace highest) before calling (highest 3 2 10). You will then see that the second call looks like this:
(highest '(2 10))
Then the &rest parameter sees one object which happens to be a list.

To correct this, use APPLY. APPLY is like funcall but its last argument must be a list and is treated as if it was 'spliced onto' the function call. Like this:
(apply #'highest (cdr args))

Answer (score 3):

The `&rest` form collects all the rest of the parameters passed as a list itself. In the case of the `highest (&rest args)`, `args` is actually a list with an element, a list. That is, in the call, `args` value is `((3 2 10))`.

The second version of `highest` with the `&rest` modifier always enters in the second test of the condition, as `args` is just a list with one element (that happens to be a list). You return the first element of `args`, which is the list itself, `(3 2 10)`.

The difference with both constructs is that the first version, in which you pass the list as a parameter, the function receives the list as the only parameter of the function. In the case of `&rest`, all the arguments (in this case just one) are collected into a list (in this case with just one element).

**EDIT**: As per your edit, as Thomas states in his comment, using `&rest` implies you have to use `apply` to call recursively. This is the correct implementation:

```
(defun highest (&rest args)
    (cond
        ((null args) nil)
        ((null (cdr args)) (car args))
        (T (higher (car args) (apply #'highest (cdr args))))))
```

(note the `apply` in the last line).